# String manipulation - replace string with given limit

Tags: vba, excel

I want to replace a string with given string by specifying starting and ending position.

for example:

```
var1 = "REPLACE THIS IS STRING SAMPLE TEXT"
var2 = "REWRITE"
```

In the var1 replace the string in the position  1 to 8 with var2

Any help indeed...

Thanks :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
var1 = Replace(var1, Mid(var1, 1, 8), var2)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
var1 = "REPLACE THIS IS STRING SAMPLE TEXT"
var2 = "REWRITE"

Dim str As String

str = Mid(var1, 8, Len(var1))
str = var2 & str
```

Answer (score 1):

`Mid` is quite interesting.

```
Sub MidDemo()
var1 = "REPLACE THIS IS STRING SAMPLE TEXT"
var2 = "REWRITE"

Mid(var1, 1, 8) = var2
Debug.Print var1
''Result: REWRITE THIS IS STRING SAMPLE TEXT
End Sub
```